# Windows 8 app is debug

Tags: c#, windows-8

Is there a way to checkin app.cs is curent state of app debug or deployment?

Or the problem is that I want to exceute piece of code only when debuging application.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use the `#if DEBUG` directive like so

```
#if DEBUG
    //code here only executes in debug
#endif
```

So if you want some code that runs in DEBUG and some that is in RELEASE you do it like this:

```
#if DEBUG
    //code here only executes in debug
#else
    //code here only executes in release
#endif
```

And as DAKL [has explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12693774/10779) you could also use the Conditional attribute.

Comment: Both syntaxes are valid but the #if directive allows for #else and its syntax is also shared with C++.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")] for that.

If you want a method only to be executed in debug mode you can do the following:

```
[ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]
public void WriteOnlyInDebug(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

This method is only called in Debug mode.
The method and all calls to it are getting removed from the binary when you build your app in release mode.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers tell you how to check at runtime if your app is compiled as a Debug build. If you're wanting to see if Visual Studio (or any other debugger) is attached and debugging your app you can use **System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached**.

Comment: I think you mean "at compile time" in your first sentence.